# I want to pull a variable from a jscript file to provide the href value in an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm a front-end web designer, so I only dabble in javascript etc. I've been googling this (I'm not good at jscript, but can figure it out 75% of the time); all I've been able to find is how to create variables from within HTML, which isn't helpful. I've defined a variable that makes use of a value that a function in my linked jscript file has created.

So ideally:

```
<script src="myJscriptFile.js" language="javascript"></script>

<a href="nameOfVarFromFile" >The File!</a>
```

I'm actually trying to pull the URL of a PDF file, and then use that URL in an object embedded in the page. I just figured this was a much simpler way to ask the question and get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to reference the Javascript variable *from* Javascript, and set the link's `href` from there.

```html
<a href="#" id="linktoset">The File!</a>

<script src="myJscriptFile.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script>
  document.getElementById('linktoset').href = nameOfVarFromFile;
</script>
```